# How can I remove the URI for home page in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

In Ionic, the home page always shows example.com/#/home. Is there a way for me to have the home page as example.com/#/ without the home slug?

If I do `location.go('')` on my homePage.ts file it will intermittently redirect me back to my previous page and not end up on the home page. If I add a setTimeOut, it works without issue but it seems like a wonky solution:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.location.setUri('');
    }, 0);
}
```

My guess is that I'm changing the URI state before the router has a chance to run and so it redirects me back to my previous page without the setTimeout making it wait until the next tick. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this is ultimately to upgrade from Ionic 3 to Ionic 4 and use the new angular router instead of Ionic's. There was no way to do a blank URI in Ionic 3, and now there is in Ionic 4.